# How does `std::osyncstream` manage the out stream?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, c++20

I wonder how a `std::osyncstream` object prevents data race conditons? Does it lock some mutex?

I'm specifically talking about the below program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <syncstream>


void worker( const std::size_t startValue, const std::size_t stopValue, std::ostream& os )
{
    for ( auto idx { startValue }; idx < stopValue; ++idx )
    {
        std::osyncstream out { os };
        out << "thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id( ) << "; work: " << idx << '\n';
    }
}

void runThreads( std::ostream& os )
{
    std::jthread t1 { worker, 10000, 20000, std::ref( os ) };
    std::jthread t2 { worker, 20000, 30000, std::ref( os ) };
}

int main( )
{
    std::ofstream file { "out.txt" };
    runThreads( file );
}
```

The source of the above code can be viewed [here](https://github.com/mCodingLLC/VideosSampleCode/blob/master/videos/088_endl_vs_newline_multithreaded/main.cpp). Although I have made slight modifications to make it better and safer.

This simple program prints 20,000 lines into a file without generating a messy output.

**The possible output:**

```
thread: 2; work: 10000
thread: 3; work: 20000
thread: 2; work: 10001
thread: 2; work: 10002
thread: 2; work: 10003
thread: 2; work: 10004
thread: 2; work: 10005
thread: 2; work: 10006
.
.
.
```

What's going on behind the scenes? How do these two threads communicate with each other? Do they have separate copies of `syncstream` object? How does this object (i.e. `out`) manage the output stream `os`?

Comment: This seems to be a good article about [synchronized output streams](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/synchronized-outputstreams) from Rainer Grimm's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Does it lock some mutex?*

Yes, indirectly. The `std::basic_osyncstream` class, of which `osyncstream` is a specialization of the form `basic_osyncstream<char>`, is derived from `std::basic_ostream` and will typically have just one 'extra' member, of the `std::basic_syncbuf` class. [From cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_osyncstream):

> Typical implementation of std::basic_osyncstream holds only one
> member: the wrapped std::basic_syncbuf.

It is that `basic_syncbuf` object that implements the output synchronization, preventing data races. Again, [from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_syncbuf) (bolding mine):

> Typical implementation of std::basic_syncbuf holds a pointer to the
> wrapped std::basic_streambuf, a boolean flag indicating whether the
> buffer will transmit its contents to the wrapped buffer on sync
> (flush), a boolean flag indicating a pending flush when the policy is
> to not emit on sync, an internal buffer that uses Allocator (such as
> std::string), ***and a pointer to a mutex used to synchronize emit
> between multiple threads accessing the same wrapped stream buffer***
> (these mutexes may be in a hash map with pointers to basic_streambuf
> objects used as keys).

Comment: "*wrapped stream buffer*", so this is the buffer that all `osyncstream` objects have access to? And they try to modify it?

Comment: @digito_evo Well, I'm not part of either the Standards Committee or the implementers; however, I would *assume* that each instance of a *different* stream would have access to a different mutex/buffer. So, every instance of one created wit `std::cout` would share the same sync_buffer.